# Algorithm - Make Highest Tower

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I've a problem that I could not resolve. I've thought many solutions but no one seems to  work.

So that's my problem:

You're given n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>, .... n<sub>k</sub> LEGOs, each one with a even number of faces.
Every LEGO can be stacked up another one only if :

- the upper LEGO has the same face of the LEGO under it;
- the upper LEGO must have a number of faces that is less or equal to the number of faces of the LEGO under it.

In addition to this every face has an opposite face which is inserted by input after the first one;
example: LEGO1 - face1, face2, face3, face4 (face1 and face2 are opposites such as face3 and face4).

The problem asks to make the highest tower with these LEGOs using each LEGO only once.
The tower must have only 1 direction so it can go only from left to right or from bottom to the top.

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad English :/

INPUT EXAMPLE:

Lego1 - f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6

Lego2- f33, f47, f98, f123

Lego3 - f4,f127

OUTPUT EXAMPLE:

2

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Is it a homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's not an homework....found it on some graph exercises and i'm trying to do it but i can not resolve it.
Already tried to consider every LEGO with all his faces as many differents LEGOs and after that I tried to sort them from the one with the smallest number of faces to the highest one and then applying a similar algorithm to LIS problem, but it keeps not working :/

Comment: If the restriction is strictly less, I think is a DAG and can be solved by dynamic programming, but I have no idea about equal...

Comment: the restriction it's not strictly less, but it's just less so they can have an equal number of faces, too ...

Answer (score 1):

Resembles a task I had long ago. Idea of the algorithm was:

- put items (legos) in circular list (closed single-linked list);
- make function which

  - in loop

    1. takes next element from the list (deletes it)
    2. recursively cals itself
    3. inserts previously deleted element
    4. advances to the next element

When list gets empty You have got one of possible lego sequences. Algorithm builds all possible seaquences using each list element only once.

Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 4

struct CList{
   int d;
   struct CList *next;
};

void search(struct CList *pstart);
void result(struct CList *v[MAX], const int nv);

int main(){
   static struct CList lst[MAX];
   struct CList *p = lst;
   int i;
   for( i = 0; i < MAX - 1; i++){
      lst[i].d = i;
      lst[i].next = lst + i + 1;
   }
   lst[MAX-1].d = MAX - 1;
   lst[MAX-1].next = lst;
   search( p );
   return 0;
}

void search(struct CList *pstart){
   struct CList *p, *pp;
   static struct CList *v[MAX];
   static int nv = 0;
   if( pstart->next == pstart ){
      v[nv++] = pstart;
      result( v, nv );
      nv--;
      return;
   }
   nv++;
   p = pstart;
   do{
      pp = p;
      p = p->next;
      v[nv-1] = p;
      pp->next = p->next;
      search( pp );
      p->next = pp->next;
      pp->next = p;
   } while( p != pstart );
   nv--;
}

void result(struct CList *v[MAX], const int nv){
   int i;
   for( i = 0; i < nv; i++ ){
      printf(" %d ", v[i]->d);
   }
   puts( "" );
}
```

In Your case further optimization may be possible (for example breaking the recurson when current element dosn't stack).